# How to run script in Pyspark and drop into IPython shell when done?

Tags: python, ipython, apache-spark

I want to run a spark script and drop into an IPython shell to interactively examine data.

Running both:

```
$ IPYTHON=1 pyspark --master local[2] myscript.py
```

and

```
$ IPYTHON=1 spark-submit --master local[2] myscript.py
```

both exit out of IPython once done.

This seems really simple, but can't find how to do it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you launch the iPython shell with:

```
$ IPYTHON=1 pyspark --master local[2]
```

you can do:

```
 >>> %run myscript.py
```

and all variables will stay in the workspace. You can also debug step by step with:

```
>>> %run -d myscript.py
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to pass the context variable though. sc (default). Thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Launch the IPython shell using `IPYTHON=1 pyspark`, then run `execfile('/path/to/myscript.py')`, that should run your script inside the shell and return back to it.