# How to access SparkContext in pyspark script

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The following SOF question [How to run script in Pyspark and drop into IPython shell when done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934778/how-to-run-script-in-pyspark-and-drop-into-ipython-shell-when-done) tells how to launch a pyspark script:

```
 %run -d myscript.py
```

But how do we access the existin spark context?

Just creating a new one does not work:

```
 ---->  sc = SparkContext("local", 1)

 ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing 
 SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local) created by <module> at 
 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py:204
```

But trying to use an existing one .. well *what* existing one?

```
In [50]: for s in filter(lambda x: 'SparkContext' in repr(x[1]) and len(repr(x[1])) < 150, locals().iteritems()):
    print s
('SparkContext', <class 'pyspark.context.SparkContext'>)
```

i.e. there is no variable for a SparkContext instance

Comment: What happens when you run this first: `from pyspark import SparkContext`?

Comment: With Spark 2.0.0 onwards, the `sparkSession` which you can create without a clash has a `sparkContext` property to access the original context.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Include the following:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
```

and then invoke a static method on `SparkContext` as:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: sc is the existing SparkContext OP is looking for. Earlier there was no way to obtain an existing SparkContext, but the static method getOrCreate() was added to get and existing context or create a new one if one does not exist.

Comment: It works for me! 3x! but can you explain that please?

Answer (score 9):

If you created a already a SparkSession:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StreamKafka_Test") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Then you can access the "existing" SparkContext like this:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Answer (score 4):

**Standalone python script for wordcount** : write a reusable spark context by using **contextmanager**

```
"""SimpleApp.py"""
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf


SPARK_MASTER='local'
SPARK_APP_NAME='Word Count'
SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY='200m'

@contextmanager
def spark_manager():
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster(SPARK_MASTER) \
                      .setAppName(SPARK_APP_NAME) \
                      .set("spark.executor.memory", SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY)
    spark_context = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    try:
        yield spark_context
    finally:
        spark_context.stop()

with spark_manager() as context:
    File = "/home/ramisetty/sparkex/README.md"  # Should be some file on your system
    textFileRDD = context.textFile(File)
    wordCounts = textFileRDD.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    wordCounts.saveAsTextFile("output")

print "WordCount - Done"
```

**to launch:**

```
/bin/spark-submit SimpleApp.py
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type pyspark at the terminal, python automatically creates the spark context sc.

Comment: That's the bin/pyspark *program* not a standalone pyspark *script*.

Comment: And sc variable is not created automatically, SparkContext instance is created automatically.